# WP8 application for replace standard watches on lock screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a possibility for Windows Phone 8 to write application to replace standard clock on lock screen?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an app can only provide the background image, or be one of several apps to provide notifications (icon, #, message--in the bottom area of the screen).  One app can provide detailed status, and up to 5 can provide quick status.

For more details, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207048(v=vs.105).aspx

The count, text, and icon are defined in the primary application tile (i.e. the lock screen mirrors the application, if the user lets it).  For more detail, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/06/03/enable-lock-screen-notifications-in-your-wp8-app.aspx

Comment: How often app provided detailed status can refresh it? And can you add link to some info about creating app with detailed status?

Comment: I correctly understatnd, that detailed status it messages like calendar(text "Windows Phone 8 write..." on screen)?

Comment: yes, you can configure your app so that the count, icon, and text on app's primary tile is used on the lock screen.  I've added a link to the answer